# maximum recursion depth problem for SVM regression in rpy2

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, svm, rpy2

I'm getting an error of `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` in my python coede while I tried to run an SVM regression in R using line magic via rpy2. but the same code is having no error if I'm doing that using cell magic in a separate cell. The problem is when I write this in a python cell as line magic. (I'm running the code in jupyter notebook).

This is the code (python version = 3.9.13, rpy2 version = 3.5.1).

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris_data = load_iris()
Data = pd.DataFrame(data=iris_data.data, columns=iris_data.feature_names)

from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects as ro

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    R_Data = ro.conversion.py2rpy(Data)

%R -i R_Data
%R library('e1071')
%R model_full <- svm(R_Data , R_Data['sepal length (cm)'])
%R full_pred <- predict(model_full , newdata = R_Data)
```

This is giving the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`
but if I'm using cell magic instead of line magic, it is giving the output. But I want to integrate this inside a python class. So, line magic is needed. (I tried to change the recursion limit using sys. but that is not working).